# Bitmap becomes null

Tags: java, android, firebase, bitmap, firebase-storage

I am working on a project in which I have to pass data from an activity to another. I try to use bitmap in order to pass around images. After I retrieve the image from Firebase storage I can output it with System.out but if I try to read it outside the fetch method it returns null in console.

```
 for (DocumentSnapshot result : Objects.requireNonNull(task.getResult()).getDocuments()
                ) {
                    title = Objects.requireNonNull(result.get("Author")).toString();
                    author = Objects.requireNonNull(result.get("Title")).toString();
                    edition = Objects.requireNonNull(result.get("Edition")).toString();
                    isbn = Objects.requireNonNull(result.get("ISBN")).toString();
                    category = Objects.requireNonNull(result.get("Category")).toString();
                    reviews = result.get("Reviews");

                    Bitmap[] bitmap = new Bitmap[1];

                    try {
                      final File local_file = File.createTempFile("android_dev", "jpg");

                        storageRef.getFile(local_file).addOnCompleteListener(bitmap_task -> {
                            if (bitmap_task.isSuccessful()){
                                System.out.println("Sucess");
                                bitmap[0] = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(local_file.getAbsolutePath());

                                 System.out.println(bitmap[0] + " yes yes");
                            }else {
                                System.out.println("Failure!");
                            }
                        });

                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    if (category.equals(finalBook_category)) {
                        if (title.contains(search) || author.contains(search) || edition.contains(search) || isbn.contains(search)) {
                            System.out.println(bitmap[0] + "What is happening");
                            books_list.add(new LibraryBook(author, title, edition, isbn, category, reviews, bitmap[0]));

                        }
                    }
                }

                setAdapter();

            } else {
                System.out.println("Nope");
            }

        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you referring to this line

```
System.out.println(bitmap[0] + "What is happening");
```

as the point where you don't see the expected bitmap output? If so, it's because the `getFile()` is method that returns a `Task`, with the `addOnCompleteListener` callback. So it's not synchronous. So your code is reaching this section:

```
                    if (category.equals(finalBook_category)) {
                        if (title.contains(search) || author.contains(search) || edition.contains(search) || isbn.contains(search)) {
                            System.out.println(bitmap[0] + "What is happening");
                            books_list.add(new LibraryBook(author, title, edition, isbn, category, reviews, bitmap[0]));

                        }
                    }
```

before the bitmap has been fetched from your storage bucket. Put that if statement below this line instead:

```
System.out.println(bitmap[0] + " yes yes");
```

so that it waits until the callback and you know you have downloaded the image before using it.

Comment: I tried that before asking this and I had a very weird error because I forgot about also including the setAdapter() method. Thank you for your time!